# React Native - Pushing new component using Code push (OTA)

Tags: react-native

We are working on a problem statement where we need to push new components (view) every week to end-user. This component could be as complex as a Carousel or an advancedd Card (img with content).

can we push these components for ex. below code using Code Push API?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const HelloWorldApp = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      }}>
      <Text>Hello, world!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default HelloWorldApp;
```

Comment: AFAIK, yes you can. However, you can't code push if you have a new asset, new library added/updated, etc.

Comment: do you have any working examples which you point here, as per my understanding all Native View gets compiled into Native code? Now to change something in native code, I don't think it's a straightforward task. can you please comment on it